# Spring security customer token enhancer not invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have added a custom token enhancer using java configurations as given below

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.jdbc(dataSource).withClient("abcd").secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT").scopes("read", "write", "trust") 
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 1) 
                .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(60 * 60 * 24 * 30); 
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore()).tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain).userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()").realm(REALM);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JdbcTokenStore(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
        return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("123");
        return converter;
    }

}
```

Below the Custom token enhancer

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
        final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
        additionalInfo.put("organization", authentication.getName() + randomAlphabetic(4));
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
        return accessToken;
    }

}
```

I have run the application on debug, and had a debug point on CustomTokenEnhancer's enhance method. Now when I hit the oauth/token method for generating the token, it is not going into the enhance method.

Please suggest if I am missing anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see you assign token enhancer anywhere. As far as I remember you need something like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    endpoints
        // some code here
        .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer());
}

@Bean
@Primary
public AuthorizationServerTokenServices tokenServices() {
    DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
    // some code here as well
    tokenServices.setTokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer());
    return tokenServices;
}

// Beans beans beans

@Bean
public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
    return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
}
```

After that you should get your token enhancer involved.

Comment: I have added the bean tokenServices() but still the same

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same problem, even though I implement the below:

```
public class CustomTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer {
@Override
public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication) {
    final Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
    additionalInfo.put("organization", authentication.getName() + randomAlphabetic(4));
    ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
    return accessToken;
}
```

}

the token enhacer does not get called because there was a register in the table  **oauth_access_token** corresponding to the default table of spring oauth, I solved the problem just  deleting the record corresponding to client-id and username.

Comment: Thank you! You've just saved my day

Comment: Thanks a lot. you saved my day as well.. i mean night

Answer (score 3):

Your CustomTokenEnhancer is not called because you're using a JdbcTokenStore and some access tokens have been cached in the database.

Manually delete records in this table *oauth_access_token* and try again.

See this issue for reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/1371

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your customer enhancer is CustomTokenEnhancer.

```
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints){
            TokenEnhancerChain enhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();

            enhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter));
            endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore)
                    .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter)
                    .tokenEnhancer(enhancerChain)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenGranter(tokenGranter(endpoints));
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
            return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
        }
```